# why does fopen fail when given value from main( argv[])

Tags: c, fopen

this is my program

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    initscr();
    FILE *fd;
    char *ProgFile;

    ProgFile = argv[1];
    printw(ProgFile);
    refresh();

    fd = fopen(ProgFile,"rb");

    if( fd==NULL )
    {
        printw("error");
        perror ("The following error occurred");
        refresh();
    }
    else
    {
        printw("bin file loaded: '%s'",ProgFile);
        refresh();
    }

    getch();
    endwin();

    return 0;
}
```

when run it given this error message: No such file or directory.

but if i hardcode ProgFile = "filemname.bin"; then the program works perfectly.

when the program is run both versions print filemname.bin when asked the value of ProgFile.

I have been trying to solve this for 2 days and have no idea what is happening. can anyone tell me what is wrong ?

this is c++ on linux centos

Comment: Does the program open the file when the path is hardcoded? (And why are you using `stdio` in C++ instead of `iostream`?)

Comment: Have you checked the working directory? Access permissions? Can you stat() the file?

Comment: @arne the file is fine and opens when hardcoded just not when the name is passes in. im thinking it may be some king of type mismatch issue but i dont know enough about it to debug it any further.

Comment: @Skeith, were you running both versions of the program in the same directory? (There can't be a type error since pathnames, as far as `fopen` is concerned, are just `char` arrays.)

Comment: @larsmans both programs are in the same folder along with the file and only one is run at a time.

Comment: @Skeith: files aren't sought for in the directory where the program resides, but in your current working directory. From which directory did you execute them?

Comment: @larsmans there is a folder on my desktop, both versions of the program and the file are in the folder. i know this cannot be the problem as the program that is hard coded opens the file fine.

Comment: @Skeith: that's not what I asked. In what directory was your shell when you ran the programs? If you ran them by double-clicking, try running them from the command-line.

Comment: @larsmans i use a launcher. this opens the terminal and types the string passed to it. i tried typing it manually as you say and it worked so how it worked if i do it manually ? how can i fix my launcher ?

Comment: @Skeith: set it's working directory, or start directory, to the directory containing the file.

Comment: @larsmans could you write your comments intp an answer so i can accept it :)

Comment: Just a quick note: Your code uses `perror` to print the error of `fopen`, but `errno` could be set by `printw` if it fails itself. Try to avoid this in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A program looks for relative filenames (those not starting with `/`) in its present working directory; this is inherited from the parent, which is the shell if you execute the program from the command line, and can be set explicitly when you run it from a starter. So, you need to make sure the program is started in the same directory that the file is in.

(You could also use an absolute path or do an explicit `chdir` system call the directory where the file is, but both are ugly and make it pretty much impossible to move the program around.)

Answer (score 3):

First, this is C and not C++. I don't see any C++ in your code.

This

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    FILE *fd;
    char *ProgFile;

    ProgFile = argv[1];
    printf(ProgFile);

    fd=fopen(ProgFile,"rb");

    if( fd==NULL )
    {
        printf("error");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("bin file loaded: '%s'",ProgFile);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Works perfectly fine for me. Make sure you're passing the right argument and the correct path. I suggest you passing the whole path, and not just *filemname.bin*.

Comment: your using a different library to the one im using. ncurses is supposed have stdio in it but im not sure if its exactly the same. also are you running the program on linux ?

Comment: Ncurses does not "have `stdio` in it". It only includes the header.

Comment: It doesn't matter. Those libraries are just for displaying the result. The point is that fopen gets the argument right. And sadly no, I'm at work so I had to try on Windows XP (using GCC anyway). Anyway, Windows/Linux... it doesn't matter. That code works, and will do in any OS. I insist that your problem is with the file path. Put the full path and not only the file name and it will work.